# How to replace object when dropping an item over it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a drag-drop system where users need to match an image of an animal to its name i.e. dragging the word cat on top of the image of a cat. I'm able to get the word to snap onto the image but for some reason they swap positions! I.e the image of a cat swaps back to the 'word bank'! I've included my onDrop function which shows what's currently going on. Just to clarify I'd like the word to be on-top or replace the image it's being dropped on.

```
public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (!item)
    {
        DragHandler.itemBeingDragged.transform.SetParent(transform);
    }
    else
    {
        Transform aux = DragHandler.itemBeingDragged.transform.parent;
        DragHandler.itemBeingDragged.transform.SetParent(transform);
        item.transform.SetParent(aux);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "swap positions"

Comment: Of course, sorry for my lack in clarity. Basically when you drag the word "cat" over the image of a cat, the word takes the position of the image but the image replaces the original position of the word....  I have a list of words on the screen where the user needs to drag onto the corresponding image. At the moment when the word is dropped onto the image the image itself takes the original place of the word! I don't want this behaviour to happen but instead have the word snap ontop or replace the image.... sorry I don't think I explained that well too!

Comment: I think it may be something to do with the ```item.transform.SetParent(aux);``` ?

Comment: Why do you parent everything ? You should just do word.transform.position = image.transform.position (and maybe add an offset so it is not "in" the image)